# Click event in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to append the url of the parent page an iframe is located in based on the current url within the iframe.

This is all taking place on the same domain, so I don't think there should be any security issues.

EDIT:

My code now looks like the following:

```
function locator_url() {

var iframeUrl = alert(document.getElementById("dealer-        locator").documentWindow.location.href);

var iframeUrlSplit = iframeUrl.split('/locator/');

window.location.hash = '#' + iframeUrlSplit[1];

};


$(document).ready(function(){

    document.getElementById("dealer-locator").contentWindow.onload = locator_url(); 
});
```

Now the default src for the iframe is http://localhost/meade/locator/
The page the iframe is on is http://localhost/meade/dealerlocator/

The code works for the initial page load, the parent url is appended to localhost/meade/dealerlocator/#

However, when I click a link inside the iframe the parent url doesn't change, even though the href value in the iframe has.

The parent url should have it's hash updated to something like:

localhost/meade/dealerlocator/#results_list.php?showonly=US&tab=US&zip=&distance=10&state=&city=&name=

But that's not happening.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
document.getElementById("dealer-locator").contentWindow.onload = locator_url;
```

Comment: Using that with locator-url changed to locator-url() worked but only for the initial iframe load. If I clicked a link within the iframe the new url doesn't seem to be getting read.

Comment: Are you sure the iframe window gets reloaded when you click a link?

Comment: What would prevent it from reloading when I click a link?

Comment: None of them are hash links or using ajax to load content without a refresh. Everything is either a form button link or a normal text link

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need click events in your iframe, then you could do it this way:

```
<a href="http://www.car.com" onClick="parent.locator_url(); return false;">Car.com</a>
```

Then `locator_url()` gets called in the parent page.  Same goes for using load events (I mean, load events that occur in the iframe context).